# I need help in creating regex for JavaScript where minimum 10 digit number is allowed and maximum 15. It may optionally have "+" at the start only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create regex for use in JavaScript where minimum 10 digit number is only allowed and maximum 15 digit. It may optionally have "+" at the start only and not at any other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression

```
^\+?\d{10,15}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2b8oHy/1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can do the work

```
var patt = new RegExp("^([+]([0-9]){10,15}$)|^(([0-9]){10,15})$");
```

Comment: @esqew Actually, the solution works, it was formatted poorly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems my comment is a bit misleading after your edit - the `+` token in v1 of this answer would have thrown an error.

Comment: @esqew It was like this all the time, my edit was fixing the formatting, I just added a newline and 4 spaces before `patt`, see [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61393504/edit/baf89752-09cc-4b49-8f3c-fcef2ac50b58)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right - my mistake. I've deleted my original comment and rescinded my downvote as such.